# Fastest way to add decimal place(s) after parseFloat(), similar to Python's float()

Tags: javascript

As far as I know JavaScript's `parseFloat()` does not add decimal place (i.e. `.0`) to the number, while Python's `float()` does. I want `parseFloat()` to have similar behaviour as `float()` and want it to run as quick as possible.

I've come up with two rough solutions to achieve this, but I am quite sure they are not the quickest:

---

*Method 1:*

```
function handle_prec(number)
{
    if (Number.isInteger(number))
    {
        let log = Math.log(number) / Math.log(10);
        let precision = Math.ceil(log) + 1;
        return (parseFloat(number).toPrecision(precision));
    }
    else
        return number;
}
```

*Method 2 (a bit dumb but more straight-forward):*

Add `".0"` to the end of the number if it's an integer then parse it back to float.

---

What is the best or fastest way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: if you want xx.0 as number in javascript? you can't, instead you can convert it to string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python distinguishes between integers and floats. JavaScript does not, except in very limited circumstances. Thus, parsing back to float will return it to the original state (where `1` and `1.0` are the same thing). The only way to distinguish `1` and `1.0` in JavaScript is in string form.

Your code is basically it, except the whole `if` true block can be replaced by `number.toFixed(1)`. Replacing that, and condensing the function a bit:

```
const handlePrec = number => Number.isInteger(number) ? number.toFixed(1) : number;
```

with caveat that this will return a string for integers, and original type for everything else. If you want it to return a string always:

```
const handlePrec = number => Number.isInteger(number)
    ? number.toFixed(1) : String(number);
```